# App engine datastore denormalization: index properties in the main entity or the denormalized entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Consider the classic example of blog data modelling, where we have a `Blog` entity with many properties, and we want to list the latest blogs in a page.

It makes sense to denormalize the `BlogPost` entity into a `BlogPostSummary` entity which will be shown in the list view, avoiding fetching and deserializing many unwanted properties.

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
  title = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.TextProperty()
  created = db.DateProperty()
  ...

class BlogPostSummary(db.Model):
  title = db.StringProperty()
  content_excerpt = db.TextProperty()
```

The question is: which entity should hold the indexed properties? There are 3 options:

### 1. Index properties in both

- Pros:

  - Easy query on both entities.
- Cons:

  - Maintaining denormalized indexes is expensive.

### 2. Index properties in main entity only

- Pros:

  - Indexing properties in the main entity is more safe, as the denormalized entity is treated as redundancy.
- Cons:

  - Querying the list view will need a double roundtrip to datastore: One to key-only query for `BlogPost` entities, followed by a batch get for `BlogPostSummary`.

### 3. Index in denormalized entity only

- Pros:

  - The list view can be easily built by a single query.
- Cons:

  - The main entity cannot be queried by those properties anymore.
  - The indexes occupy more space when the denormalized entity is a child of the main entity.

Which option would work better? Are there other options?

Would the double round trip to datastore in option 2 be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is an abstract question that does not have a "correct" answer. The choice of a data model depends on specific requirements of a project, including:

- usage patterns (how often you need access to different data)
- update patterns (e.g. separating frequently updated properties from stable properties in order to reduce write costs)
- average performance and extreme-case performance requirements (e.g an average blog may have 10 posts, a very popular blog may have 10,000 posts)
- ability to use memcache to reduce datastore trips and improve performance
- data complexity (i.e. how many different kids of entities depend on this particular entity kind)
- transaction requirements
- security and access roles considerations (e.g. not exposing private data by mistake)

By the way, there is another way to model data in the Datastore - using child entities. For example, blog posts may be child entities of a blog entity. This way you can retrieve all blog posts with a single query by providing a parent key - without storing post IDs or keys in the blog entity or blog ID/key in the post entities.

Comment: You simply split one entity into two entities, and I honestly see no reason for that. You can move the excerpt property into the BlogPost model - it will work faster and it will be cheaper.

Comment: `BlogPostSummary` is used in a list view, where only `title` and `content_excerpt` are used in that list view. `BlogPost` has many properties, and fetching all of them for a list view item is unnecessary.

Comment: You can return a "light" version of an entity to the client, and then come back for a complete entity if necessary - using a cheap and fast `get`. You can also leverage memcache - some blog posts will be much more popular than others, and the hot list will change all the time. This is an ideal situation for using memcache.

Comment: If you do decide to separate the entity, either create a child entity with a single "full content" property, or create a separate "PostContent" entity using the ID of a BlogPost entity as its ID. This way you can always `get` full content using an ID of the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid fetching and deserializing unwanted properties, then put all your entities into a single model and use [Projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries):

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
  title = db.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  content = db.TextProperty(indexed=False)
  content_excerpt = db.TextProperty(indexed=False)
  created = db.DateProperty(indexed=True)
  ...

posts = BlogPost.query().fetch(projection=["title", "created"])
```

(Note that the projection fields must be indexed.)

Comment: Unfortunately, as you mentioned, the projected properties must be indexed. In your example, it is not possible to make the equivalent of `BlogPostSummary` as `content_excerpt` is not indexed, and indexing it doe snot make sense.